# installing pymultinest on anaconda 3

Tags: python-3.x, installation, anaconda3

I have tried installing pymultinest as is recommended on https://github.com/conda-forge/pymultinest-feedstock on the anaconda powershell prompt:

```
    conda config --add channels conda-forge
    conda config --set channel_priority strict
    conda install pymultinest
```

but I get the error:

```
    PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

      - pymultinest
```

and I really don't understand why!